# Editorconfig property name to control method argument indent

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation, auto-indent, editorconfig

I try to find the name of the argument in editorconfig or setting in Intellij Idea (java) which is responsible for the next indent.
Continuation indent works fine if I use code inside function, but for method arguments on the next line they are always starting from the opened brace `(`.
I would like it to have the same value as continuation indent.

See picture:
[image]